# Sending queries from client to WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, architecture, soa

I would like to have your take on the following.

We're looking at SOA as a solution to some conceptual problems we have. We don't want to built the same logic several times. So want to make some WCF services and have different cliënts retrieve data through these services (perhaps even Apple apps). The ideal situation being that the cliënts are as thin as possible, only being concerned about presentation. All the business logic and data access should be taken care off in the WCF service(s).

Now my boss looked into this and his biggest concern is basically that we'd fall into chaos. He imagines we'll be defining a new method for each query we want to execute on the database, roughly said.

So like:

- RetrieveCustomerById
- RetrieveCustomerByName
- RetrieveCustomerByStoreId
- RetrieveCustomerWithPersonalDetailsButWithoutAddressById
- etc...

So his idea is to have cliënts construct queries and send it to the WCF services. The WCF services execute the queries, apply bussiness logic and returns the results.

I am very much interested in all the con's or pro's you guys can come up with. Thank you in advance for thinking with me.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a SOAP-style WCF service? Or a RESTful one?

Either way, I'd be tempted to have a set of optional parameters by which you can make the request, so taking a RESTful service as the example, you'd have a set of additional query string parameters to retrieve customers by.

e.g.:

/Customers?id=ID
/Customers?name=NAME
/Customers?StoreId=STORE
/Customers?id=ID&withPersonalDetails=true&withPersonalDetails=false

of course, if you're predominantly getting by ID then

/Customers/{id}/

would be a good service URL.

Equivalent stuff would work on the SOAPy side, with a bunch of nullable parameters in the request.

The advantage would be the client would only have to know what it knows about the customer, and could just provide that to the service which could tackle the more complex task of working out what the query needs to be before retrieving the customer. The disadvantage would be that it would be possible for the client to craft requests that didn't provide enough information to get the customer.

But at least you wouldn't have to worry about the client providing invalid queries.

EDIT:

As to *why* it's a bad idea to have the client providing queries - the brief answer is "it breaks [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding), and introduces lots of [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29#Disadvantages)". The long answer is that the client is now dependent on implementation details of the service. Say the layout of the database changes, ideally you want to change as little as possible - in a nicely encapsulated system you'd have to update the persistance layer, and possibly nothing else. If your client is required to understand the schema you have to update all the layers all the way up, which is obviously bad.

Second, if the client is providing queries, you're implicitly trusting the client - you've got a big job on your hands to restrict what the client can do - think what happens if someone starts impersonating your client and running arbitrary queries against your database - eek!

Third if you need to fix a query, if it's in the client you have to update the client code and push an update to all the clients (and some may not take it, leaving those users with the bug) if it's encapsulated in the service you only have to fix the problem there.

Fourth, where are your business rules now enforced? In the client. With a service between client and database all your business rules are in one place which you nicely control.

Effectively if your client is crafting database queries, it may as well be directly attached to the database - which is fine in many circumstances. But if you want to be able to abstract database access behind a service, update / fix your business rules in one place, and limit your liability from malicious clients, then it's a really bad idea.

(I'm sure there are dozens of other reasons, these are off the top of my head, before my morning cup of tea.)

Comment: If it's a SOAP service, you could have a single parameter that takes a "SearchParameters" object where the entire search is nicely defined.

Comment: **@Massif:** <br/>
First off all thnx for replying ofcourse, but sorry. Wether it's SOAP or RESTfull is not important for this discussion. See my response to Aliostad. 

Let me clarify the problem more for you. My boss wants to do something like this:

/Customers?query="SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE ID = 1"

This is breaking all common practices on so many levels, but we want arguments why we shouldn't do this. So why shouldn't we do this you think?

**@Tridus:** <br/>
Same goes for you as for Massif. Thnx for replying ofcourse. Please see what I wrote to Aliostad and Massif.

Answer (score 1):

Your boss is probably right, it is what more or less what it will look like but

- First of all, what is necessarily wrong with it (although read till the end as some of them do not make sense)?
- There will be no `RetrieveCustomerWithPersonalDetailsButWithoutAddressById` since `CustomerWithPersonalDetailsButWithoutAddress` is a different domain model.
- Passing queries to the business logic very much reminds of the old times when in interfaces parameters where being defined as `object` (or if you are as old as I am `Variant` in VB6 COM). This means *we do not want to spend the effort and take up the challenge of understanding our domain*.
- `RetrieveCustomerByStoreId` will not be needed since if it is related to the store, it is responsibility of the store repository to provide it.

All in all, if you follow DDD, passing query will just make the design very sloppy.

Comment: My boss = from 'Variant VB6 COM' era. He even argues why we should have 3 tiers. He says it makes fixing problems 3 times longer. While I ofcourse say the opposite.

Now you see why he wants to construct the queries at client side, pass them to a service. Service executes the provided query, applies some logic and sends data back.

I really have to get back to basics with my boss. Simply stating we would break DDD is not an argument for him. Forget everything you've ever known about programming. Now... Tell me why we shouldn't provide SQL queries (as Strings) as parameters to a service.

Answer (score 1):

Have you think using WCF Data Service ?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668794.aspx

Comment: **@Jean-Christophe Fortin:** <br/>
Yes, I have. But the DB is not ready for Entity Framework (and I find WCF Data Services most usefull in combination with EF), plus we also want Business Logic at the server side.

Answer (score 0):

> So his idea is to have cliënts construct queries and send it to the WCF services. The WCF services execute the queries, apply bussiness logic and returns the results.

It is called [`Specification Pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) and it is frequently used in `DDD`.

One service method that takes a specification parameter is enough to handle 95% of object requests.

[`EntityQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422815%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) class in `WCF RIA Services` is an example, how specification pattern can be used in client-service architecture.